# Laravel (Eloquent) Table || Peer equivalent

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, eloquent, propel

Propel uses `Peer` classes, and doctrine used `Table` classes as a way to manipulate respective objects and object properties, without having to pollute the actual object with `static` methods.

After cursory glance of the laravel (eloquent) docs, I didn't see anything that eloquent provides for the same `Peer` or `Table` like functionality. My question is, does laravel (or eloquent) provide a namespace for such classes, or do I just use `Table` and let autoloader take care of the rest?

```
// Example use of a table class in doctrine 1.2
$user = UserTable::getInstance()->findById(1);
```

**-- Update 1 --**

Layman example of how a doctrine table class may be used:

```
class UserTable
{
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
    }

    public function linkFoo($userId, array $foos)
    {
        $user = $this->findById($userId);

        foreach ($foos as $foo) {

            $user->foo = $foo;

            $user->save();
        }
    }
}

// SomeController.php
executeSaveFoo()
{
    UserTable::getInstance()->linkFoo($this->getUser(), array('foo1', 'foo2'));
}
```

The purpose of the doctrine table class is to provide an api for actions against respective objects which should not be in the controller, in the above example the `linkFoo` class will link provided foos to the respective user object.

I feel the separation between objects and 'table' classes is important, as an object shouldn't know how to instantiate nor hydrate itself.

Comment: Can you explain what your example above accomplishes or what exactly it's doing?

Comment: With Eloquent you only have one class per model (and usually database table) but you don't have to "pollute" it with anything. Please read the documentation and/or clarify what your problem is.

Comment: I didn't say pollute it with 'anything', I was specific about 'static' methods. Does it make sense to pass the object to itself per the above example?

Comment: In Laravel you would create a Command class to execute the logic inside linkFoo(), rather than having it in your Model class, and call it from your controller; passing the user and array to the Command class.

Comment: @aethergy: Nice, if you would be so kind to post an answer with a basic example, I can accept, and possibly help other old school ORM users.

Comment: Besides commands you could also create a repository or use general service classes. Laravel / Eloquent doesn't force you into one pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, there is more than one way to accomplish the task, but here's a quick example using Commands.

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//...
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;
use App\Commands\UpdateUser;
use App\User;
//...

class UserController extends Controller {

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
{
    //gather request data
    $data = $request->all();

    //retrieve user
    $user= User::findOrFail($id);

    //update user
    $updateUser = \Bus::dispatch(
                        new UpdateUser($user, $data)
                     );

    //check if update was successful
    if($updateUser)
    {
        //update successful
        return redirect('/route/here')->with('message', 'User updated successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        //else redirect back with error message
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Error updating user');
    } 
}
}
```

The `UpdateUserRequest` class would handle validation.

**Command**

```
namespace App\Commands;

use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class UpdateUser extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $user, $data;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     */
    public function __construct($user, $data)
    {
        $this->user= $user;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //assign first name
        $this->user->first_name = $this->data['first_name'];

        //assign last name
        $this->user->last_name = $this->data['last_name'];

        //assign email address
        $this->user->email = $this->data['email'];

        //update user
        if($this->user->update())
        {
            //updated successfully, return true
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //else return false
            return false;
        } 
    }

}
```